# Software to run a simulation on different strategies on the game battleships

Tags: windows, gratis, open-source, game, simulation

As stated I would like to run a simulation for the game battleships on my windows computer. I want to be able to program the game with pseudorandom positions for the battleships and then create a loop that tries to find all ships based on a tactic i programmed. I would like to run this simulation for a lot of tries to see which tactic requires the least amount of guesses.

I would really appreciate a recommendation for a software capable of doing this. I am not willing to spend money on a license though. I do have a license for mathematica though and have worked with mathematica on a project for university, but I am having a lot of trouble programming useful loops and algorithms there.

Thank you very much for any answers!